# How can I get these loops to stop combining results?

Tags: vb.net

I wrote some code that adds a certain amount of points to a test score based on whether the original score is less than 50 or greater than 50. Everything is going well, except for when a number is close to and below 50. For example, if I add 7 to the score if the number is below 50, add 4 if the number is above 50, and the number is 49, it adds 7 and 4 instead of just 7. How can I get it to only add what I want?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'declare variables
        Dim scores(5) As Integer 'array of 6 variables named scores with inded values of 0-6
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim add1 As Integer
        Dim add2 As Integer

        For i = 0 To scores.Length - 1
            scores(i) = Val(InputBox("Input six scores:", "Enter Scores"))
        Next i

        add1 = Val(Me.txtBelow.Text)
        add2 = Val(Me.txtAbove.Text)

        For i = 0 To scores.Length - 1
            If scores(i) < 50 Then
                scores(i) = scores(i) + add1
            End If
            If scores(i) > 50 Then
                scores(i) = scores(i) + add2
            End If
        Next i
        For i = 0 To scores.Length - 1
            Me.lblOutput.Text = Me.lblOutput.Text & scores(i) & " "
        Next i
```

Comment: Use `ElseIf`...

Answer (score 0):

Use `ElseIf` syntax.

Example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement :

```vb
    Private Function CheckIfTime() As Boolean
        ' Determine the current day of week and hour of day.
        Dim dayW As DayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
        Dim hour As Integer = DateTime.Now.Hour

        ' Return True if Wednesday from 2 to 3:59 P.M.,
        ' or if Thursday from noon to 12:59 P.M.
        If dayW = DayOfWeek.Wednesday Then
            If hour = 14 Or hour = 15 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        ElseIf dayW = DayOfWeek.Thursday Then
            If hour = 12 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```